# Не могу вывести список через JList

Tags: java, swing

Считал с файла информацию а теперь надо вывести её в виде таблицы не пойму как это сделать вот код:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
            String line;
            String [] colum={"Марка авто","Модель авто","Рік виготовлення авто","Ціна авто"};
            List<Vehicle> cars = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                    String[] p = line.split("\\s+");
                    Vehicle v = new Vehicle(p[0], p[1], Integer.parseInt(p[2]), Integer.parseInt(p[3].replaceAll("\\.", "")));
                    cars.add(v);
                }
            }
            JList CarsTable=new JList();
            JFrame frame=new JFrame("Таблиця автомобілів");
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.setSize(640,480);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода таблиц используйте JTable.

Пример:

```
String [] colum={"Марка авто","Модель авто","Рік виготовлення авто","Ціна авто"};

    Object[][] data = {
    {"Toyota", "Corolla", "2012", "20000"},
    {"BMW", "350i", "1986", "5000"},
    {"Mercedes", "123", "1989", "2500"}
    };

    final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

Пример от Oracle: [The Java™ Tutorials:How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Да я понимаю что вы хотите мне сказать,но у меня при считывании создается обьект который записывается в List<Vechine> я хочу вывести информацию именно из него.Ваш способ я уже видел на других сайтах мне просто надо использывать именно этот массив